# How to connect to Mongo DB in Docker from Scala Play Framework?

Tags: mongodb, docker, scala, playframework

I have a Mongo DB Docker container running on `192.168.0.229`. From another computer, I can access it via:

`> mongo "mongodb://192.168.0.229:27017/test"`

But when I add that configuration string (`host="192.168.0.229"`) to my Play Framework app, I get a timeout error:

```
[debug] application - Login Form Success: UserData(larry@gmail.com,testPW)
[error] p.a.h.DefaultHttpErrorHandler - 

! @7m7kggikl - Internal server error, for (POST) [/] ->
 
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[TimeoutException: Future timed out after [30 seconds]]]
```

In the past, the connection was successful with `host="localhost"` and even an Atlas cluster (`host="mycluster.gepld.mongodb.net"`) for the hostname, so there were no problems connecting previously with the same code. For some reason, Play Framework does not want to connect to this endpoint!

Could it be because the hostname is an IP address? Or, maybe Play/ Akka is doing something under the covers to stop the connection (or something to make Mongo/Docker refuse to accept it?)?

I'm using this driver:

`"org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "4.4.0"`

Perhaps I should switch to the Reactive Scala Driver? Any help would be appreciated.

---

Clarifications:
The Mongo DB Docker container is running on a linux machine on my local network. This container is reachable from within my local network at `192.168.0.229`. The goal is to set my Play Framework app configuration to point to the DB at this address, so that as long as the Docker container is running, I can develop from any computer on my local network. Currently, I am able to access the container through the mongo shell on any computer:

`> mongo "mongodb://192.168.0.229:27017/test"`

I have a Play Framework app with the following in the `Application.conf`:

```
datastore {
     # Dev
      host: "192.168.0.229"
      port: 27017
      dbname: "test"
      user: ""
      password: ""
}
```

This data is used in a connection helper file called `DataStore.scala`:

```
package model.db.mongo

import org.mongodb.scala._
import utils.config.AppConfiguration

trait DataStore extends AppConfiguration {

  lazy val dbHost = config.getString("datastore.host")
  lazy val dbPort = config.getInt("datastore.port")
  lazy val dbUser = getConfigString("datastore.user", "")
  lazy val dbName =  getConfigString("datastore.dbname", "")
  lazy val dbPasswd = getConfigString("datastore.password", "")

  //MongoDB Atlas Method (Localhost if DB User is empty)
  val uri: String = s"mongodb+srv://$dbUser:$dbPasswd@$dbHost/$dbName?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
  //val uri: String = "mongodb+svr://192.168.0.229:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb"
  System.setProperty("org.mongodb.async.type", "netty")
  val mongoClient: MongoClient = if (getConfigString("datastore.user", "").isEmpty()) MongoClient() else MongoClient(uri)
  print(mongoClient.toString)
  print(mongoClient.listDatabaseNames())
  val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName)
  def close = mongoClient.close() //Do this when logging out
}
```

When you start the app, you open `localhost:9000` which is simply a login form. When you fill out the data that corresponds with the data in the `users` collection, the Play app times out:

```
[error] p.a.h.DefaultHttpErrorHandler - 

! @7m884abc4 - Internal server error, for (POST) [/] ->
 
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[TimeoutException: Future timed out after [30 seconds]]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.$anonfun$convertToPlayException$2(HttpErrorHandler.scala:381)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:242)
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.convertToPlayException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:380)
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:373)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:264)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:430)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:422)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:454)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Future timed out after [30 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait0(Promise.scala:212)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:225)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.$anonfun$result$1(package.scala:201)
    at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread$$anon$3.block(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3118)
    at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread.blockOn(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:172)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.blockOn(BatchingExecutor.scala:116)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:124)
    at model.db.mongo.DataHelpers$ImplicitObservable.headResult(DataHelpers.scala:27)
    at model.db.mongo.DataHelpers$ImplicitObservable.headResult$(DataHelpers.scala:27)
```

The call to the Users collection is defined in `UserAccounts.scala`:

```
case class UserAccount(_id: String, fullname: String, username: String, password: String)

object UserAccount extends DataStore {

  val logger: Logger = Logger("database")

  //Required for using Case Classes
  val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[UserAccount]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)

  //Using Case Class to get a collection
  val coll: MongoCollection[UserAccount] = database.withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry).getCollection("users")

  //Using Document to get a collection
  val listings: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("users")

  def isValidLogin(username: String, password: String): Boolean = {
    findUser(username) match {
      case Some(u: UserAccount)  => if(password.equals(u.password)) { true } else {false }
      case None  => false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the whole piece of config you use for DB connection + the whole stacktrace + the related code calling Mongo?

Comment: To clarify: the Play app is running in a container or directly on your machine?

Comment: Thank you for commenting @GaëlJ . I have updated the question with more details. With all of the interrelated parts of Play apps, please let me know if I didn't provide all of the information you requested.

Comment: Did you debug the connection string. It seems to me you are using empty user and password but still outputting `:` between them.

Comment: Yes I did, using the commented-out line below it.

Comment: @GaëlJ thank you for looking into this issue. I believe I have solved it. This line in my connection program was making the connection look at the default ("localhost") rather than connecting to an off-site DB instance:

```  val mongoClient: MongoClient = if (getConfigString("datastore.user", "").isEmpty()) MongoClient() else MongoClient(uri)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI if anyone runs into this problem. I had a bad line in my `DataStore.scala` file:

```
val mongoClient: MongoClient = if (getConfigString("datastore.user", "").isEmpty()) MongoClient() else MongoClient(uri)
```

Since I was trying to connect without a username (there's no auth on my test db), the above line was saying, "If there's no username, you must be trying to connect to the default MongoClient() location, which is localhost". My mistake.

I simply changed the above line to this:

```
val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(uri)
```